# Want my formated DIV to be converted to PDF and sent through email on a single click. Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a PHP page powered by jQuery. A singel page has four steps, controlled by jQuery.

In diffrent steps, user selects two Images from two galleries (step 1 & 2), fromats a table by arranging divs inbetween (setp 3) then filling a form (step 4).

I want: when user clicks "Finish" on step 4. All the above information be converted to PDF and emailed to the provided email address.

Please suggest me idea, tool, plugin or code to do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time that I tried to auto-generate PDFs as you mentioned, I used a php library called fpdf.  As I recall, it was difficult and cumbersome.  My lack of knowledge/experience/patience definetly made me not have much fun working with it.  Give it a shot and see if looks like it is feasible for you.  The site has some getting started examples, and a quick Google search should yield some examples too.  URL: http://www.fpdf.org/

I just stumbled across another library that looks promising: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/  I have not used it, but, if I need to do this again in the future, I would try this before going back to fpdf.

I don't know of any javascript/jQuery plugins that can generate a PDF, so I think you are stuck with PHP in this scenario.

Hope that helps a bit!

EDIT:  The email part is simple, I really like Swift Mailer: http://swiftmailer.org.  It is simple to use, lots of examples, and supports a variety of options, like, attachments.  Also handles the encoding issues that generally plague emails sent directly from php mail().

One more thing, if you are not too far into development, take a look at using Kohana as a php framework.  It's light and easily extensible.  They follow decent coding standards, and have an active open source community.  Plus, there is a module for SwiftMailer that almost sends the mail for you-Not really...but I think you get the point. ;)

Comment: Dear Jonathan, Thanks for your quick and comprihensive response.

Comment: I am already messing with "fpdf" but the main problem is to send the 'table and DIVs' things to this pligin VIA php :(

Comment: An HTML table represents the four walls of a room, divs are dynamically added to represent doors and windows on each wall. I want this formated "Walls + Door n Widows" to go into PDF along with other information collected in diffrent steps and email it.

Comment: Interesting usage.  Do you have an example I could look at it?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to directly add the DOM elements to the PDF.  This is something I would absolutely love to be able to do. My guess is that you will need to recreate the tables, etc, based on coordinates of the items on the screen.  jQuery should be able to give you pretty accurate offset coords so that you could build a pretty close representation in PDF.

Comment: Have you thought about using the Canvas, or Svg tags?  You might be able to use one to allow the user to build the model, and then export it as an image onto a pdf.  That would likely simplify the PDf work you would need to do.

Comment: Well, my work is still not published on web but the prototype i was given to follow can be seen at [link](http://www.kutchenhaus.co.uk/Quote/QuoteControl.aspx?quotetype=QQA&R=&A=&LID=&doorID=537#). I am currently working on "fpdf" and will let you know if got success.

Comment: Just got a lead! downloaded a Class "TCPDF" from [www.tcpdf.org](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Read few examples from documentation, seems delecious. Lets hope it will help pushing myself out of this mess :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://andreasgal.github.com/pdf.js/

Comment: As far as I can tell, pdf.js is only a pdf reader.  I understood Khaled's question as him needing to edit/save/send a pdf file.  Whether I am right or wrong, great find for a JS viewer!  Bookmarked!

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Something went wrong inbetween understanding the question and jumping to a conclusion :)